# How to stop OTP authentication while recording the script in Loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

One of my application after sign in getting otp to mobile and we have option that don't ask for 30 days if we click this check box then it will not send otp up to 30 days but while recording script with LoadRunner 
and reply the script always sending otp to mobile.

I have tried multiple times with different setting but no luck. My LR version is 12.60

please assist anyone for this case.

Comment: How does it know not to ask for 30 days? You need to simulate this to have it not ask. Most likely you can't otherwise someone attacking your website would do it too. You need to ask the development team to have some workaround in your internal environment.

Comment: Hi Buzzy, Thanks for info. In application we have option that don't ask for 39 days , once we check this option then it won't ask for 30 days , it is working manually but in Loadrunner it's not working every time asking OTP. is there any setting need to do?

Comment: You need to ask the dev team how this works behind the scenes. It is a security measure and if it is implemented correctly you cannot overcome it easily. If it works by setting a cookie then you will need to add that cookie in your script but it could also be implemented on the server side in which case the dev team will need to provide a workaround.